# Thymeleaf add value in style

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a div block that has styles. I need to add another style with a substitution value. I imagined it like this:

`th:styleappend="background-position:-${value}%"`

But it doesn't work. Is there a possibility to do this?

Comment: Yep, you need to make your string a valid expressions.  I suggest `th:styleappend="|background-position:-${value}%|"` or `th:styleappend="${'background-position:-' + value + '%'}"` -- see the section on [literal substitutions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you are having a syntax issue here. Try the following code:

```
th:styleappend="'background-position:-' + @{${value}} + '%'"
```